# calling methods in MVC2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

how to call a method within a method in the controller from a model.

Comment: I think you're going to have to expand a bit on your question to receive helpful answers.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call a method in a controller from a model because you don't have the instance of the controller. The only way would be to pass the instance of the controller to the model so that it can call the method but that would be bad practice. So if a model needs to call a method on the controller you are doing something wrong.